# Datatables Border applies to all rows

Tags: datatables

I have a table in a fixed horizontal space. I want to add a border to the bottom of the table.

It seems very difficult, and I'm wondering if there's a setting, but all the docs only have info about cell borders.

Here's some things I've tried:

- Adding `border:"1px solid grey"` to the table init.

  - This does nothing.
- Giving a table wrapper a border:

[image: Where I want the border]

- Giving the table a border via css `table {border-bottom: 1px solid grey}`:

[image: Table border only gives rows a border]

- Giving the footer a top border is too long and over reaches, not giving me the effect I want.

### Here's the desired outcome:

[image]